# how to dynamically give buffer value in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

i ve a string , for example:

```
NSString *str = @"12,20,40,320,480"
```

This str has to be given as buffer value,

```
UInt8 *buffer;
```

Now how to give the str as buffer value? The value of str string keeps changing , and hence buffer has to dynamically take the value as str everytime. 
plz help me how to achieve this.

Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean by "how to give the str as buffer value"? Please rephrase your question and add more context.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty unclear but if you want to create an array of UInt8s from a NSString that stores a comma separated list of numbers you have to parse the string to individual numbers and then convert each number's string representation to a UInt8 representation

Something like but with extra code for validating the NSString input:

```
NSString *str = @"12,20,40,320,480";

NSArray * str_a = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
UInt8 * buf = malloc(sizeof(UInt8) * [str_a count]);

int i;
for(i=0;i<[str_a count];i++)
    buf[i] = atoi([[str_a objectAtIndex:i] cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);

// do something with the buffer
somefunction(buf);

// free the buffer
free(buf);
```